# Counting prefixes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've written 2 functions in haskell, and now i have to write a third one, for calculating the number of prefixes in haskell. here's an example:

i have to lists. the first is the prefixes list, and the other one is the text list. what this function is suppose to do, is to calculate the number of times each word from the prefix list is a prefix of all the words in the text list, and present it in a tuple (word, number of times it appears as a prefix in the text words:

prefix list ["go", "co"]

text list ["golf", "company", "count"]

this should return [("go", 1) , ("co", 2)]

what i have so far is this:

```
isPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPrefixOf [] _ = True
isPrefixOf _ [] = False
isPrefixOf (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y  && isPrefixOf xs ys


prefixCount :: (Eq a1, Num a) => [a1] -> [[a1]] -> a
prefixCount _ [] = 0
prefixCount x (y:ys) | isPrefixOf x y = 1 + prefixCount x ys
                 | otherwise = prefixCount x ys



howManyPrefixes _ [] = 0
howManyPrefixes [] _ = 0
howManyPrefixes (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x, prefixCount x (y:ys))
```

Any help?

Comment: If you use `Ord` instead of just `Eq`, you'll have access to `sort`, `sortBy`, `group`, and `groupBy` from `Data.List`.  I'd play around with those first.

Comment: @bheklilr You don't need any of those, the `Ord` constraint is unnecessary when you're just checking prefixs.

Comment: @jozefg You do need `Ord` for `sort` (I incorrectly thought it was needed for `group` as well), and while this can be solved without `Ord` (as your answer points out), but I was attempting to lead dcarou towards a potential solution I saw using one or more of those functions.

Comment: I have to use a recursive solution

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` this is quite easy

```
howManyPrefixes ps ws = zip ps $ map (`prefixCount` ws) ps
```

Now since this looks like homework I'll let you write the recursive solution yourself, some helpful hints.

1. You're almost there with your current solution
2. Don't check if the second list (the one your counting prefixs in) is empty. This is the second clause of your current solution.
3. In your last clause, add the recursive step by consing that tuple onto the resulting
   list from `howManyPrefixes xs (y:ys)`
4. Don't pattern match on the second list, eg `y:ys`. It doesn't matter if it's empty.

Comment: yes, this is actually homework haha, nicely spotted let me tell you that! But what i'm struggling with is the fact that i don't see how i can make it check for prefixes for the first word in the text, and then the others. I believe i solved it for the first word, but then i get lost.. i've done this                                   howManyPrefixes [] _ = 0
howManyPrefixes (x:xs) (y:ys) | (x, prefixCount x y)
                              | otherwise = howManyPrefixes xs (y:ys)

Comment: @dcarou The key to this is: First write a function that counts the prefixes for one word. Once you have that, use that in map.

Comment: So to count the prefixes for one word i have this : howManyPrefixes (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x, prefixCount x y), adding map it would look something like this ? howManyPrefixes (x:xs) (y:ys) | map (x, prefixCount x y) ? this is not recursive, but i'm not sure if i should use the "otherwise" guard here

Comment: Consider the result of `map (\x -> prefixCount x ys) xs`. What would this be? How could that help you?

Comment: @Ingo from the definition of map, it would return a list containing all the elements, but i still don't see a solution to it recursively

Comment: @dcarou No. It would return a list of prefix counts for all elements of xs, counted in ys. In your example, it would return [1,2]. Btw, you could have checked that in ghci.

Comment: i tried, but it didn't compile. can you give me something recursive to solve this ? i'm really not seeing it

Comment: @dracou no matter if you use map directly or write a recursive solution, as I said before, the key is to do it for one thing first. Then, to do it for a list of things. For practicing: how would you add 3 to each elemnt of a list?

Comment: So basically, why is this incorrect ?                               howManyPrefixes [] _ = 0
howManyPrefixes (x:xs) (y:ys) | map (\x -> prefixCount x ys) xs
                              | otherwise = howManyPrefixes xs (y:ys)